# Convert Woocommerce products to Wordpress Posts

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I don't need WooCommerce anymore and I am switching/converting all woocommerce products to wordpress posts. I have used [Post Type Switcher](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/) Plugin, but this is not what I need. I need to convert all product attributes and details and show them in post page. How do I do this?

Comment: you have to write plugin to fetch all attributes and meta data into post content.

Comment: could you please explain more?

Comment: you have to write script that will grab all attributes and other data from products and insert into post content, then you can delete all the products and uninstall woocommerce.

Comment: You may want to consider hiring a developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php

// Setup your query
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'product',
 'tax_query' => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'type', //Custom attribute
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'custom_type', 
      ),
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'color', //Custom attribute
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'orange', 
      ),
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'size', //Custom attribute
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'medium', 
      ),
  ),
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

//Get specific meta data from product
$product = get_product($loop->post);

?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>

    <!-- color attribute of product -->
    <p class="color">Color of product: <?php echo $product->get_attribute('color'); ?></p>
    <!-- size attribute of product -->
    <p class="size">Size of product: <?php echo $product->get_attribute('size'); ?></p>
    <!-- color attribute of product -->
    <p class="type">Category: <?php echo $product->get_attribute('type'); ?></p>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); // Remember to reset 

?>
```

It will obviously work differently according to your attributes etc.

Comment: `get_product()` should be `wc_get_product()`. However, the OP isn't planning on using WooCommerce any longer, so that function would not be available.

Comment: I agree @helgatheviking but it looks like they want to not use the shopping cart anymore and just have the product. Since woocommerce posts are Wordpress posts, this is the simplest solution so you don't have to recreate posts again when it's already there.

Comment: If that's what the OP really wants then you shouldn't need a new `WP_Query()` as the shop archive would still work. The question is unclear about intent.